# How do I solve "Cannot find name 'Record'" (or other utility types) when using Typescript with JSDoc?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jsdoc, tsc, tsserver

Is it possible to use the Utility types, such as Record when using `JSDoc` + `tsserver` in plain JavaScript?

(I'm trying to create a setup that gives me as many of the gains of TypeScript as I can stand, without the transpiling)

## Sample Code

I happen to actually need a map, which I understand is defined in TypeScript as "Record":

```js
let http = require("http");

/**@type {Record<string, Person>} */
let people = {
  "1234": { name: "Bob" },
  "abcd": { name: "Jane" }
};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end(JSON.stringify(people));
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

## Error

However, when I try to use it I get this error:

```
[tsserver] Cannot find name 'Record'. [E]
```

## Config

Version:

`tsc --version`:

```
Version 4.3.5
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ESNEXT",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["DOM"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./cache",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

For reference, this is how I set ale to use `tsserver` in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ale_linters = {'javascript': ['tsserver', 'jshint']}
```

Comment: what does the IDE show when you just hover over `Record`? I get a full description of what `Record` does in typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Record` type is defined in `lib.es5.d.ts` so you need to add at least `es5` into your `lib` array.

If you don't set `lib`, it defaults to `target`, but if you set it, basic es libs must be manually included (commonly used for environments with polyfills, but don't support new language features).

Comment: Could you give a specific example of what that looks like?
Like { lib: ["liba", "libb", "libc"] }? Or { lib: ["target", "libc"] } Or what? And do you know where I find the documentation for it?

Comment: Follow up: comment out // "lib": []. Set "target": "es6" or "esnext" or whatever.